# Domain-driven-design (DDD) pitfalls

Tags: domain-driven-design

I am quite new with DDD and would like to know about any pitfalls you might want to share. I will summarize it later for more newbies to read :)

Thanks

Summary so far:

- [Anemic domain model](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anemic_Domain_Model) where your entities are primarily only data bearing and contain no business logic
- Not using bounded contexts enough
- Focusing too much on patterns

There is a good presentation on this topic as well [here](http://vimeo.com/13824218) (video).

Comment: You should probably make this question community wiki.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Probably the most important one: not grokking the central, fundamental principle of the Domain Model and its representation in Ubiquitous Language.  With the plethora of technology options around, it's very easy for your head to fill up with ORMs, MVC frameworks, ajax, sql vs nosql, ... So much so there's little space left for the actual problem you're trying to solve.

And that's DDD's key message: don't.  Instead, explicitly focus on the problem space first and foremost.  Build a domain model shorn of architectural clutter that captures, exposes and communicates the domain.

Oh, and another one: thinking you need Domain Services for everything you can do in the domain model.  No.  You should always first try to put domain logic with the Entity/Value type it belongs to.  You should only create domain services when you find functions that don't naturally belong with an E/V.  Otherwise you end up with the anaemic domain model highlighted elsewhere.

hth.

Comment: I find quite truthful idea that need for domain service is a sign of yet unrecognized aggregate root.

Comment: Wow. This is melting my mind. Please take a look at [my question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4300859/56145).

Comment: Your second rule is not a DDD rule, it is a simple OO concept. Code in a wrong abstraction level smells.

Answer (score 15):

One of the biggest pitfalls is that you end up with a so-called [anemic model](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anemic_Domain_Model) where your entities are primarily only data bearing and contain no business logic. This situation often arises when you build your domain model on top of an existing relational data model and just make each table in the database an entity in your domain model.

Comment: I agree on this one. Was the first one I fell into

Comment: For new people, I disagree with this. DDD isn't one philosophy for implementation, rather one philosophy for arriving at implementations, of which the possibilities are endless.

Comment: So you don't recommend using functional programming?

Answer (score 13):

You might enjoy [presentation](http://vimeo.com/13824218) of Greg Young about why DDD fails.

In short:

- Lack of intent
- Anemic Domain Model
- DDD-Lite
- Lack of isolation
- Ubiquitous what?
- Lack of refinement
- Proxy Domain Expert (Business analyst)

Answer (score 7):

Not using [bounded contexts](http://devlicio.us/blogs/casey/archive/2009/02/11/ddd-bounded-contexts.aspx) enough. It's toward the back of the the big blue book but Eric Evans has gone on record as saying that he believes that bounded contexts and ubiquitous language are THE most important concepts.

Similarly, people tend to focus too much on the patterns.  Those aren't the meat of DDD.

Also, if you do not have a lot of access to domain experts you are probably not doing DDD, at best you are DDDish.

More concretely, if you end up with many-to-many relationships, you've probably designed something wrong and need to re-evaluate your aggregate roots/contexts

Answer (score 5):

Only adding to what others have already said;
My personal experience is that people often end up with an anemic model and a single model instead of multiple context specific models.

Another problem is that many focus more on the infrastructure and patterns used in DDD.
Just because you have entities and repositoriesand are using (n)Hibernate it doesn't mean you are doing DDD.

Comment: _Just because you have entities and repositoriesand are using (n)Hubernate it doesnt mean you are doing DDD._ Excellent

Answer (score 4):

It's not from my personal experience with subject, but it was mentioned for a couple of times in DDD books and it's what I've been thinking about recently: **use Entities when you really need identity, in other cases use Value Object**. I.e., Entity pattern often happens to be the default choice for any model noun, and it's not the way it should be.

Comment: However, don't use value objects with EF. Just don't. (Jimmy Bogard has an EF DDD Scorecard, link is currently broken)

Answer (score 3):

Beware of the **[Big Ball of Mud](http://www.laputan.org/mud/)**.

One of the pitfalls of domain driven design is to introduce ambiguity into a model.  As explained in the article [**Strategic Domain Driven Design with Context Mapping**](http://www.infoq.com/articles/ddd-contextmapping):

> Ambiguity is the super-villain of our
>   Ubiquitous Language

This may happen when two distinct concepts share the same name, or when the same concept can have different uses.  It may be necessary to

> expose the domain structure in
>   terms of bounded contexts in a context
>   map

If a model is used in too many different ways, or has too many responsibilities, it may be a sign that it should be divided.